# Initializing a static variable in a function to a non-constant value

Tags: c, static, constants

I have a function that needs some constant data, but retrieving the constant data requires calling a function that performs a linear search to retrieve the data. I don't want to perform the search for each call of the function, so I tried making the variable in question `static`. But static variables cannot be initialized to non-constant values:

```c
int my_function(int foo)
{
    static const Thing *bar = thing_from_name("bar");

    return do_thing(foo, bar);
}
```

GCC rightly complains that the "initializer element is not constant".

After pondering my situation for a moment, I came up with a way to have my cake and eat it too:

```c
int my_function(int foo)
{
    static const Thing *bar = NULL;
    if (!bar) bar = thing_from_name("bar");

    return do_thing(foo, bar);
}
```

This appears to work fine so far, but it feels... wrong. Are there any pitfalls to this approach? Is there a better way to solve my problem?

To be clear, `thing_from_name` is effectively a pure function, in that it only reads from constant data in memory. Since it searches for a string, there's not really an easy way for me to optimize it down to a constant expression (as far as I know).

EDIT: here's a rough outline of what `thing_from_name` does, for further context:

```c
const Thing *thing_from_name(const char *name)
{
    const Thing *t;

    for (t = &thing_array[0]; t->name != NULL; t++) {
        if (strcmp(t->name, name) == 0) {
            return t;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: That's why `constexpr` were invented in `C++11` :)

Comment: Are you multi-threading?  Does `thing_from_name` allocate memory either directly or indirectly? If the answer to those questions is "No", then your proposed solution is perfectly valid, and is in fact quite common.

Comment: Can you supply pseudo-code for the 'thing_from_name()' function?  Perhaps it would help explain your predicament.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer, I've added an outline of what it does to the post.

Comment: @user3386109, I think I'm technically multithreading because I'm using GTK, but IIRC all userland code executes in a single thread unless you explicitly tell GTK to create a new thread (which I don't).

Comment: I think that your code is OK as is. When multi-threading and/or allocating memory, you might need a `lock/unlock` mechanism to make sure that the initialization only runs once, but I don't see any need for that in your use case.

Comment: Your own solution to your problem is perfectly fine IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Likely for plain C you have to use a thing like [`Boost.Preprocessor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html). If `thing_from_name()` is expressable as completely static code, that can be pre-calculated at compile time, then you may succeed. If no, then you should use your solution but remember that it's not thread-safe.